# Getting: The target type of this expression must be a functional interface

Tags: arrays, java-8

I am using this code :

```
return Arrays.asList(dataSet.getTableNames()).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: What type does `getTableNames()` return? If it is a `String[]`, this should work, but also you are getting a `String[]` converting it to a `List<String>` and then converting it back to a `String[]`.

Answer (score 1):

[`toArray(String[]::new)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)) requires JDK 11. The confusing error message stems from the fact that there is a [`toArray` method with one parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(T%5B%5D)) but it’s incompatible with the `String[]::new`.

You can use the Java 8 method like `toArray(new String[0])` to achieve the same.

But, perhaps, you confused the Collection method with [the Stream API method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)). If you use

- ```java
  return Arrays.stream(dataSet.getTableNames()).toArray(String[]::new);
  ```

  <sup>(mind the `stream` instead of `asList`)</sup>

  if `dataSet.getTableNames()` returns an array, or
- ```java
  return dataSet.getTableNames().stream().toArray(String[]::new);
  ```

  if `getTableNames()` returns a `List` (or any kind of `Collection`)

it will work.

But this is an unnecessary detour in either case.

- If `getTableNames()` returns a `String[]` array, you can simply use

  ```java
  return dataSet.getTableNames().clone();
  ```
- If `getTableNames()` returns an `Object[]` array but is known to contain only `String` elements, you can use

  ```java
  Object[] array = dataSet.getTableNames();
  return Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length, String[].class);
  ```
- If `getTableNames()` returns a `Collection`, use

  ```java
  return dataSet.getTableNames().toArray(new String[0]);
  ```